# Make systemd change hostname without logging out

Tags: linux, systemd, hostname

I have a systemd service that reads some environment values (that may change at startup) and set the hostname accordingly.

The service at the moment is a mix of several tries

```
[Unit]
Description=Hostname Setting Service
After= read_variables.service
Requires= read_variables.service network-pre.service
Before= systemd-hostnamed.service  network-pre.service
DefaultDependencies=false

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "echo name$VARIABLE > /etc/hostname; systemctl start systemd-hostnamed"
StandardOutput=journal+console
EnvironmentFile=/folder/environment_output.txt
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is this one:

```
at n-1-th startup, environment variables are set at n-1-th value
reboot 
n-th startup
n-1-th values are read in /etc/hostname and then hostname is set to name@n-1
correct n-th values are read with  read_variables.service and put in environment_output
correct hostname is set in /etc/hostname
But hostname is not modified on the fly so I will have hostname@n-1 instead of hostname@n
```

So my question is how to run these scripts before systemD prints the line:

systemd[1]: Set hostname to XYZ

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/353597/64699

Answer (score 0):

To change hostname run:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname new_hostname_here
```

Comment: Problem is: if I launch this line in ExecStart in a service without dependencies, it works properly and runs everything as expected (real-time changing of hostname). The issue arises because of the dependencies with read_variables.service. If I include these dependency (or I think any other non-empty dependency), it seems that the hostname is one of the first things processed by systemd and there is some "hidden dependency" so the hostname-changig service is perfomed later in the start-up stage and thus the differences between the hostname and the /etc/hostname content